# Laravel/Ajax delete function not refreshing my table after success

Tags: ajax, laravel, function, sql-delete

when I add my function `fetchcategory();` in my delete ajax, my table is not refreshing:

```
        $(document).on('click', '.delete_category_btn', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cat_id = $('#delete_cat_id').val();
            alert('Category Deleted!');
            // location.reload();  
            $('#deleteCategoryModal').modal('hide'); 
            fetchcategory();
            
            //token taken from laravel documentation
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-delete/"+cat_id,
                dataType: "dataType",
            });
        });
```

for a reference, my screenshot shows the alert, showing that the delete function follows through:

[image: 1]

another reference is that my add function here reloads the page after a new table is added:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration",
                data: category_data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response){
                    console.log(response);
                if(response.status == 400) {
                    $('#category_formCheck').html("");
                    $('#category_formCheck').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                    $.each(response.errors, function (key, err_values) {
                        $('#category_formCheck').append('<li>'+err_values+'</li>');
                    });
                    }
                else  
                  {
                    $('#category_notif').html("");
                    $('#category_notif').addClass('alert alert-success');
                    $('#category_notif').text(response.message);
                    $('#createCategory').modal('hide');
                    fetchcategory();
                    }
                }
            });
```

another problem of mine is that I tried to add the alert and refresh function inside:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
```

but they do not show up, so I placed them inside `on(click`

why is my delete ajax not refreshing my table?

**UPDATE:**

- I am aware of `location.reload();` but adding this defeats the purpose.
- the data does get deleted, I have to manually refresh the whole page to see the changes though.

Comment: you can reload page using location.reload();

Comment: When you place them inside `onClick`, they are called before the item is deleted. Instead, you have to find out why they aren't called after the delete is executed. Is the delete successfull?

Comment: @JohnLobo yes i am aware, but that defeats the purpose of ajax

Comment: @shaedrich yes the delete is successful, ill update my description

Comment: Try re-adding the reload function to your delete success callback and add a console log to it to check if it is called. And you don't have any error messages in your browser dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in ajax success. I believe `fetchcategory()` method is populating data to table

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });


    $(document).on('click', '.delete_category_btn', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cat_id = $('#delete_cat_id').val();

        // location.reload();
        $('#deleteCategoryModal').modal('hide');

        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-delete/"+cat_id,
            dataType: "dataType",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Category Deleted!');
                fetchcategory();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```